# iPad + Google Map two finger zooming or scrolling on map

Tags: javascript, ios, css, google-maps, ipad

Been playing with this bug for a while, so decided to throw this question here..

I'm developing mobile page with Google Maps API, displaying some markers here and some polylines there and everything is working nicely. This is when I use page on my PC, Chrome Mobile Tools or even on my phone (Motorola 3G)..

But when I try to use this page with iPad 4 iOS v10.3.3, I can't use two finger zoom or can't scroll map view. Tried with Safari and Chrome on iPad, both having same issue. I've read many posts here on SO & Google and tried this and tried that, but nothing has helped thus far.

I've got no idea why this is happening and when I simply create new HTML-document and initialize Google Map (copy & paste "hello world" example from their documentation), it is working just fine on iPad.

So my best guess would be some CSS/JS in some part of our system is interfering with Google Maps and causing such behaviour somehow.. But I don't know what it could be or how to trace it. Or maybe it is something else.

First I thought it might be some Z-index thing where some invisible element is "blocking" map, but viewing the map on iPad isn't all non-responsive; when I "tap" with my finger two times, the map will zoom in. Also, if I click on some marker I've added it will open InfoWindow, as supposed. So it is partly working.

I've also disabled all markers and user location things for debugging. It is just plain map loading now.

I can't share too much code but I will try to share as much as possible.

This is how I initialize the map:

```
    var myStyles = [{
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }];

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gps-map'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 16,
        center: {lat: 62.260993, lng: 25.789094},
        styles: myStyles,
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        //gestureHandling: 'cooperative',
        draggable:true
    });
```

This is my HTML

```
<div data-role = "page" id = "gpsverkosto_container" data-dom-cache="false">
    <div id="main" role = "main">
            <div id="gps-map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#gps-map {
    height: 100%;
}

div[role="main"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc((115px) + 5px);
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100% - 115px);
}

.ui-mobile [data-role=page], .ui-mobile [data-role=dialog], .ui-page {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border: 0;
}
```

If I uncomment that gestureHandling, load map and try to move the map on iPad, the map will tell me to use two fingers to move. But even if I use two fingers, it won't move, or zoom.

Funniest thing is it is working just fine on other devices that I've tried..

Any suggestions? All help is appreciated.